# Sunroof style motion - conceptual issues

Tags: rigging, constraints

I'm trying to make what is essentually a sun-roof, in that the object lifts up slightly and moves back over the surrounding frame. I figure what I need is a curve and a "clamp to" constraint, but it is not clear to me the proper way to implement this. Whenever I get to the part after I select the target curve, my sunroof object jumps elsewhere. I have yet to find the combination of the below where I get satisfactory results.
I have tried:

- Making sure the origins are the same for a curve and object
- Using a bone to follow the curve (with the idea of attaching the bone to the object
- applying all transforms to the object, curve and bones
- Watching a lot of vidoes that didn't provide the information I am looking for.

My end goal is to rig up this sunroof in an array and be able to control their position all from a "control nob" empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be doable with shape keys? One key for the lifting of vertices, second key for the sliding of vertices to the side. It very much depends on what actual shape the sun-roof will have though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a follow path constraint and have the object follow a curve (yes both objects have to have their origins on the same place).

By controlling the offset you can make the object travel along the curve.

To control rotation use an empty as the control object for a copy rotation constraint.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you! although now I'm faced with the conundrum of how to array this rig without moving the origins. Oh well, thats another question.

Comment: Here's a way to  think about the Follow Path constraint: curves have a start, end and direction. When you use the follow path constraint, the object moves to the start of the curve, so **the origin of the object that follows the path will end up at the beginning of the curve**.